# Batch to find a folder in subfolders, move files one level up and delete that folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this structure:

```
    ..
    ..\FolderA\FolderX\File1.txt
    ..\FolderB\FolderX\File2.txt
    ..\FolderC\FolderD\FolderE\FolderX\File3.txt
```

I need a batch to find all "FolderX" in subfolders and move all the files in "FolderX" to one level up and delete that "FolderX"

```
    ..
    ..\FolderA\File1.txt
    ..\FolderB\File2.txt
    ..\FolderC\FolderD\FolderE\File3.txt
```

How write a batch? I tried this, but is incomplete, the code not find the folders:

```
    @Echo Off
    Set _Source=%~dp0
    Set _FindDir=FolderX
    Set _Path=%_Source%\%_FindDir%
    If Exist "%_Path%" (
    Move /-Y "%_Path%\*.*" "%_Source%"
    For /F "Tokens=* Delims=" %%I In ('Dir /AD /B "%_Path%"') Do Move "%_Path%\%%I" "%_Source%"
    RD /S /Q "%_Path%"
    ) Else (
    Echo There is no %_FindDir% folder in %_Source%
    )
```

Comment: What are parent subfolders? Folders are parent or sub but not both.

Comment: Subfolders under the batch: %~dp0

Comment: Post the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolved:

```
    @echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /d /r %~dp0 %%a in (*) do (
    if /i "%%~nxa"=="FolderX" (
    set "folderpath=%%a" (
    move /y !folderpath!\* !folderpath:~,-8!
    rmdir !folderpath!
    )
    )
    )
```

Comment: for this to constitute a good and helpful answer also for other people, you should: 1. enclose the `%~dp0` portion in `""`; 2. remove the superfluous `(` after the `set` command, and one `)` at the end; 3. change your `move` command line to `move /y "!folderpath!\*" "!folderpath!\.."`; 4. enclose path at `rmdir` in `""`;